# got Error: EPERM: operation not permitted error in React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using React native CLI to create a app but while creating build I am getting

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\reactnative\reactnative-mobile\node_modules\react-native-vision-camera\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\7371v2zs\obj\arm64-v8a\libVisionCamera.so.tmp93c4cb6'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at D:\reactnative\reactnative-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:231:14 {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\reactnative\\reactnative-mobile\\node_modules\\react-native-vision-camera\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\7371v2zs\\obj\\arm64-v8a\\libVisionCamera.so.tmp93c4cb6'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried using VS Code and Terminal as an administrator, but nothing changed. I am using the Windows OS, and I also tried giving the folder containing the app full permission from security settings, but nothing is working. The app starts but gets stuck on the start screen, and then I receive this error.

It would be very helpful if someone could assist.
Thanks!